# How can I call a web service in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, jasmine, web-testing

How can I call a web services with Jasmine ? I would like to be able to call the web service and then test and evaluate it's returned data.

I think I understand the basic of how Jasmine works, the DESCRIBE and IT functions. I've installed Jasmine 2.0. I know I have to but all my *Spec.js files into a spec directory and then launch them. I just don't know how to call a web service and to evaluate to returned data from it.

I still don't have access to the real web services that I will have to use so I'll need to practice on a free public web service.

Comment: These type of test are not recommended. Your webservice should be tested as is and have its own independent tests and the "returned value" used in JS trough your methods on jasmine.

Comment: Those "you should not do it" answers really make me mad! Who are we to determine what the user should do or not? Yes, we may provide the advice, but if we know how to do it, we SHOULD provide the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing the web service, you want to test the integration with the web service. This would involve mocking calls to the web service, then you would still need manual integration testing in an environment with the full application stack.